# Cypress stopped working with cucumber-preprocessor after 9.3.0

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have upgraded cypress version to 9.3.0 (and also tried above) from 9.2.0 and I keep getting this error from attachment.

Key thing is that I use cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I wanted upgrade to use natively .selectFile() instead of plugin.
So far I could stick to 9.2.0 but it worries me in a long run.

My plugins/index.js

```
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
const cucumber = require("cypress-cucumber-preprocessor").default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("file:preprocessor", cucumber());
};
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a bug in /plugins/index.js? Unlikely if all that happened is a version change, but can you post that file?

Comment: @Fody I have update issue description, I ran fresh cypress project with 1 simple test and cucumber-preprocessor plugin installed and got same issue fyi

Comment: Nothing wrong in the plugins/index.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it runs ok with Cypress@9.3.0 and cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@4.**3**.1 which is the latest tag on their Github repo.

But I notice that if you don't specify the version, you get cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@4.**2**.1, so I guess there's some catching up to do on npm.

In short, specify the latest version

```js
yarn add cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@4.3.1
```

Comment: Wow, it worked for me. I previously ran `npm install cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` and package.json was showing 4.3.1 so I assumed it's ok... :)